# How to handle a error inside webhook after checkout payment

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, payment-processing

I am using Stripe Checkout(Payment intent) method in my Laravel site to get the payment from the customers and then add order to the database using webhook. What if I have an error inside the webhook while inserting to a database or any error like soldout, in this case, the customer will pay but the order will not be added to the database, how to refund to the customer if the order not completed?
How to handle this situation?

Comment: if order is not completed, call the refund api.

Comment: thanks, but what can i do if i need to add backend validation before checkout to avoid some error?

Comment: may be you can validate using ajax/axios call to the backend before hitting the checkout button.